# Can't change headers with DRF APIClient()

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest

I use `APIClient()` for my tests.
I use Token auth, so I need to use [THIS](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#credentialskwargs)

If we dive into the source code we'll see next:

```py
# rest_framework/test.py
class APIClient(APIRequestFactory, DjangoClient):
    def __init__(self, enforce_csrf_checks=False, **defaults):
        super().__init__(**defaults)
        self.handler = ForceAuthClientHandler(enforce_csrf_checks)
        self._credentials = {}

    def credentials(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Sets headers that will be used on every outgoing request.
        """
        self._credentials = kwarg
```

Also I use `APIClient()` as a pytest fixture in my code:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def _api():
    """API factory for anonymous and auth requests"""

    def __api(token=None, field=None):
        api_client = APIClient()
        headers = {}

        if token:
            headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = f"Token {token}"
        if field:
            headers["X-CUSTOM-HEADER"] = field

        api_client.credentials(**headers)

        return api_client
    return __api
```

But if we create TestMiddleware to look for headers, we see next:

```py
lass TestMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self._get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        header = request.headers.get("X-CUSTOM-HEADER") # None
        header = request.META.get("X-CUSTOM-HEADER") # Works fine!
        ...

        # Response processing
        response = self._get_response(request)

        return response
```

**The question is:** Have we any way to have access to the `X-CUSTOM-HEADER` with `APIClient()` ?
Also if I use Postman it obviously works fine with `request.headers.get()`

Comment: You can set headers for specific request made by `APIClient` by passing `headers={"X-CUSTOM-HEADER": "value}` to `get`, `post` etc. Take a look how is a `X-CSRFToken'` handled in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#csrf

Comment: @wiaterb I don't think that it will work. `client = RequestsClient()` was used here, not `APIClient()`
Also I tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kwargs passed to the [`credentials()` method](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/ec29ff8a8013dd3383344bb78eea479d025e2a87/rest_framework/test.py#L282-L285) ends up feeding directly into the [constructor for a `WSGIRequest`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7d68fa4ed309a4bc13d3c8cd4b407b8915c34be8/django/test/client.py#L358-L360); this means the kwargs it accepts aren't HTTP headers, but WSGI environment variables. And HTTP headers passed as WSGI env vars are always prefixed with `HTTP_` — e.g. the `Authorization` header is configured with `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`. Also, underscores are used in place of dashes.

To have your `X-Custom-Header` header come out the other side in `request.headers` (not `request.META`, which is a copy of the WSGI env vars), pass `HTTP_X_CUSTOM_HEADER` instead of `X-CUSTOM-HEADER`.